Connecting to Heroku database issue
(First time on stack overflow) I am trying my React project with my Heroku database. the DATABASE_URL matches the URI and I feel like I have made all the correct steps I even forced: true on the db.sync    (database file) but no luck. The weirdest part is when I restart the server and refresh the page on my Heroku it will say 1 connection made but if I refresh it again it goes back to 0. It connects then it doesn't and no errors appear :(
server - index.js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("./util/database");
const User = require("./models/User");

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const authRoutes = require("./auth/authRoutes");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use("/auth", authRoutes);

// app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`));
// db.sync();

db.sync({force: true})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Database synchronized');
    // Start the server after synchronization
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Database synchronization failed:', err);
  });

module.exports = app;

database.js
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
require("dotenv").config();

const { DATABASE_URL } = process.env;

// Initialize Sequelize and connect to the database
const db = new Sequelize(DATABASE_URL, {
  dialect: "postgres",
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      require: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  }
 });

module.exports = db;

User.js
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../util/database");

const User = db.define("User", {
  email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
  password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
});

module.exports = User;

I feel like what I have is generally correct or right on the edge of correct because the database makes the connection and then goes away with another refresh
